# React Native Image Overlap

Tags: image, react-native, overlap

Assume I have two png pictures and I want to make a third one by overlapping them (like a watermark effect), and save the result on the disk. Are there some libraries for react-native to implement this?

Comment: you can overlap using css, position absolute and relative along with zIndex to overlap one after another and react-native-view-shot (@agent_hunt) to save the view

Comment: thank you for your response, seems like that's what I need, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use `react-native-view-shot` https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot . This is mainly for taking a screenshot of the view. The Layouting and overlapping can be done in react-native. If you need blurring etc, you need to make use other libraries such as react-native-blur etc